# How to save class method in database?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

Is it possible to read all the methods of a java class and save their names in the database?

```
@Entity
public class Action {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    public Action() {
    }

    public String methodA() {
        return "methodA";
    }

    public String methodB() {
        return "methodB";
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you asking if it is possible to save a Java method in a database for future use?

Comment: something like that

Comment: @medi did you try my answer below?

Comment: why do you want to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Java reflection:

```
Method[] methods = Action.class.getDeclaredMethods();

for (int i = 0; i < methods.length; i++) {
     saveToDB(methods[i].toString());
}
```

Comment: A helpful link from Oracle about using Java Reflection: https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/javareflection.html

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods()`  method which returns an array of `Method` objects including public, protected, default (package) access, and private methods, but excludes inherited methods.

```
Action  cls = new Action ();
Class c = cls.getClass();
Method[] methods = c.getDeclaredMethods();
for(int i = 0; i < methods.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(methods[i].toString());
}
```

your output will be something like that:

> public java.lang.String methodA() 
>   public java.lang.String methodB()

if you want to store **only the name** of your methods, you can use the `getName()` method. so if you do this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < methods.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(methods[i].toString());
}
```

you get this output:

> methodA
>  methodB

Answer (score 0):

You can use javassist as well to get all methods at runtime.
Even if you don't know about class structure.

```
ClassPool pool = ClassPool.getDefault();
CtClass cc = pool.get("class Name");
CtMethod[] methods=cc.getDeclaredMethods();
for(CtMethod method:methods){
 System.out.println(method.toString());
}
```